# Is possible having two buttons in one square?

Tags: button, javafx

I'm working with javafx and I need to have one square divided by its diagonal where each half is a different button, I have found how to shape a button, but I have no idea on how to code this new component.
The idea is: 
[image: How should component look like]

Each half has to be a different button as explained above, any help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of what you want to accomplish (explanations in code comments):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
  
  /*
   * You can manipulate the shape of any Region via the Region#shape property. 
   * The shape will, by default, be scaled to fit the size of the region (see 
   * Region#scaleShape property). This means you only need to set the proportions
   * of the shape.
   *
   * You'll also want to set the Node#pickOnBounds property to false. This way 
   * the mouse only interacts with the shape of the Region instead of the whole 
   * bounds which will remain rectangular.
   */

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var btn1 = new Button();
    // triangle with its 90° corner in the top-left
    btn1.setShape(new Polygon(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1));
    // only interact with the shape of the button (the bounds are still rectangular)
    btn1.setPickOnBounds(false);
    // allow the button to grow to fill available space
    btn1.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    btn1.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("button-1"));
    btn1.setStyle("-fx-base: green;");

    var btn2 = new Button();
    // triangle with its 90° corner in the bottom-right
    btn2.setShape(new Polygon(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0));
    // only interact with the shape of the button (the bounds are still rectangular)
    btn2.setPickOnBounds(false);
    // allow the button to grow to fill available space
    btn2.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    btn2.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("button-2"));
    btn2.setStyle("-fx-base: purple;");

    // a StackPane centers its children on top of each other, but since
    // we have two triangles taking up half a square the buttons will
    // appear to be positioned in the corners
    var container = new StackPane(btn1, btn2);
    // keep container square (so the triangles take up half the area)
    container.setMaxSize(150, 150);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(container), 300, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image: GIF of example application]

Unfortunately, I don't believe you can add text or graphics to the buttons. The text/graphic will still be centered on the button as if it were a rectangle. <strike>And when you set the `shape` property to a non-null value any background images are ignored.</strike> If you need more control then consider creating your own "control" (e.g. out of shapes); the reason the above uses `Button` is so you get all the built-in behavior of buttons.

Comment: technically, you can set a Text/Label node as graphic and apply transforms as needed - without a better description of what the OP wants to achieve (actually, s/he didn't provide anything except a picture which seems to be enough to lure potentially holiday-bored devs into action <g>) not much to go any further.